# Populate dropdown based on another, second one still remembers old selection

Tags: angularjs

I have an unwanted behavior: The second dropdown remembers the old item? Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/Xku9z/ (fiddle borrowed from another thread)

Scenario:

- Step 1. Select an item in the first dropdown
- Step 2. Select an item in the second dropdown
- Step 3. Select an item in the first dropdown (without selecting anything in the second one)
- Step 4. Select the same item in the first dropdown as you did in step 1.

I have no clue how to resolve this, I've been using $scope.$watch on the ng-model="option2" just to get a grip on the problem without success.

Also, by setting `option2 = null` in the `data-ng-change="getOptions2()"` wont help:

```
$scope.getOptions2 = function(){
  $scope.option2 = null;
};
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you're experiencing is easier to understand if you watch the `$scope.option2` value.

When you change the first dropdown you actually don't modify the `$scope.option2` value. It stays the same: it's remembered. To make it work like you want just add one line

```
$scope.option2 = null;
```

at end of `getOptions2` function. That's it. If you want more explanation of the current behaviour, read on.

#### Why does the second select go blank when I change the first one if the value is remembered?

`<select>` elements will show a selected value if and only if the value of `ng-model` can be found in the array bound to this element with `ng-options`.

Select first items from both dropdowns. Now:

```
$scope.option2 = "option2 - 1-1";
$scope.options2 = ["option2 - 1-1","option2 - 1-2","option2 - 1-3"];
```

As you can see the first variable can be found in the array so the value is displayed as currently selected. Now change only the first dropdown to the second item:

```
$scope.option2 = "option2 - 1-1";
$scope.options2 = ["option2 - 2-1","option2 - 2-2","option2 - 2-3"];
```

As you can see, `$scope.option2` is not changed, but it's no longer in the `$scope.options2` array. Therefore its value is not displayer as currently selected.

Comment: $scope.option2 = null; Wasn't the whole solution in my case (the fiddle was just an example). However, your further explanation made it possible for me to solve my problem. Great answer!:)